# Windows 10 shutdowns

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

My Windows 10 unexpectedly shutdowns randomly mostly like 1-10 times over day during work. I cannot found the reason why. It's completely random. Is there a concrete way to know why it happens?

```
Laptop info:
HP 8760W 17"
16Gb of RAM
```

**What i did so far and issue still occurs:**

```
 -Reinstalled Windows 10 completely
 -Power options like Lid/Sleep/Hibernate turned to Never/Do Nothing
 -Fast Run: disabled
 -Hard disks sleep: Disabled
 -Metest++ tests - OK
 -Disks tests - OK
 -ServiceHostShell access granted to admins and local service (following some internet tutorials)
 -DistibutioCOM access allow (followed some internet tips to grant access)
```

This is what i found in system event log by error type. However note that i am not sure if this is related:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Is there anyway Windows to make a log or whatever why WIndows shutdown?**

I think DistributedCOM was close to the time when windows shutdown but i cannot guaranty. As mentioned best would be Windows to log what was the cause of shutdown somewhere in file.

Comment: It sounds like this isn't a graceful shutdown, so no log can be made on the reason for the shutdown. The one instance where I have seen a laptop do this was where the motherboard had been flexed from the user slinging their laptop bag around. In the process of flexing the motherboard, they caused a short, which caused their laptop to randomly shutdown. We had a warranty on the laptop, so the manufacturer repalced the motherboard, which resolved the problem. Their laptop was shutting down every 10 minutes or so.

Comment: i don't think it's because motherboard - this laptop ais on desk almost all time.

Comment: Just in case these shutdowns are accidentally scheduled (maybe by your company) trying running 'shutdown.exe -a' in cmd and see if anything happens.

Comment: support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently installed any of the Spectre/Meltdown updates, they are now widely documented to be causing random reboots on both Intel and AMD processors. Intel and the major OEMs are all, in fact, recommending that users who experience random reboots uninstall those updates until further notice.
HTH,
--Ed--

PS: there's a pretty comprehensive list of these updates with their KB numbers at https://blog.barkly.com/meltdown-spectre-patches-list-windows-update-help#windows-updates

Comment: As far as i can see many people facing same issues due to Build 1709 which i also have. I found some tutorial to not install that build and stay with 1703. What i did so far was to uinstall Windows and install Windows build 1703 and turn on Business branch and set 365. This really helps so far and is blocking 1709 to be installed as i could saw it. So far i got no shutdowns. Perhaps this is the fix.